# http request redirect issue with express-js and cloudflare

Tags: node.js, express, web, redirect, configuration

I am build an express js server app for example as following

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 7000
const myUrl = new URL('https://www.google.com/pathname')
app.all('*',(req, res) => {
  let { query:{ redirect } } = req;
  if( redirect === true ){
    res.redirect(myUrl)
  } else {
    res.json({hi:5})    
  }
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

I made a redirection function to take some users to another domain,

when I test, the redirecting activity into localhost is working fine but when I work with production mode the redirecting activity is not working properly, for example:

On HTTP request is requested from localhost, the user is redirected from http://localhost:3003/test to https://www.google.com/pathname, and this is what I want but,

On HTTP request is requested from production mode, the user is redirected from https://my-domain/test to https://my-domain.com/pathname, and this is not what I want

FYI
my domain is connected to Cloudflare

My web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="http://web.mydomain.com/*" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:7000/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```